# Why do i get QJsonValue(undefined)?

Tags: html, c++, qt, http, asp.net-web-api

When I make request to API to get bid price, I'm getting QJsonValue undefined, and cannot display it later, what am i doing wrong?

```
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    QNetworkAccessManager m_manager;
   // make request
    QNetworkRequest request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://api.30.bossa.pl/API/GPW/v2/Q/C/_cat_name/WIG20?_t=1637005413888"));
     QNetworkReply* reply = m_manager.get(request);
     QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [reply]() {
       QByteArray rawData = reply->readAll();
       QString textData(rawData);
       qDebug() << textData;
       QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(textData.toUtf8());
       QJsonObject obj = doc.object();
       qDebug() << obj;
       QJsonValue value = obj.value(QString("_quote_min"));
       qDebug() << obj.value(QString("_quote_min"));;
       qDebug() << "Bid value is" << value.toString();;
       reply->deleteLater(); // make sure to clean up
     });
    return a.exec();
}
```

this is my json:

```
QJsonObject({"_count":1,"_d":[{"_h":"Własne - 19 listopada 2021 17:15","_hs":"Własne","_max_quote_dtm":"19 listopada 2021","_max_quote_dtm_lc":"19 listopada, 17:15","_ret_quote_dtm":"2021-11-19","_t":[{"_30d_change_max":2453.57,"_30d_change_min":2221.68,"_ask_orders_nr":null,"_ask_size":null,"_ask_volume":null,"_bid_orders_nr":null,"_bid_size":null,"_bid_volume":null,"_change":"-1.02","_change_close_open":"-1.04","_change_max_min":"+2.91","_change_pnts":-23.13,"_change_proc":-1.02,"_change_settl_ref":null,"_change_suffix":"%","_change_type":"_change_proc","_debut":"0","_group":"X1","_is_indice":"1","_isin":"PL9999999987","_live":"0","_open_positions":null,"_phase":"Zamknięcie ostateczne","_quote":"2248.18","_quote_date":"2021.11.19","_quote_imp":"2276.90","_quote_max":"2286.37","_quote_min":"2221.68","_quote_open":"2271.91","_quote_ref":"2271.31","_quote_time":"17:15","_quote_type":"_quote","_quote_volume":null,"_settlement_price":null,"_step":"2","_sw_symbol_short":0,"_symbol":"WIG20","_symbol_short":"WIG20","_time":"17:15","_transactions_nr":null,"_turnover_value":1257698337,"_type_of_instrument":"0","_volume":null}]}],"_d_fx":{"_h":null,"_hs":null,"_max_quote_dtm":null,"_max_quote_dtm_lc":null,"_t":[]},"_i":[null],"_quote_date":null,"_symbol":["WIG20"],"_type":"C","message":"OK"})
```

Comment: Is your JSON valid? Can you show us the JSON file? What line is giving the error, and what is the exact error message?

Comment: i've already added json debug, any error just: QJsonValue(undefined)
Bid value is ""

Comment: It's not very readable to put json all on one line, but I copied it somewhere else to read it. The value `_quote_min` is not in the root object of the document. You have to parse down to the right object. It looks like you'd find it in `obj._d[0]._t[0]._quote_min`.

Comment: Okay, now I see, thanks a lot, but how can i get into there now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're confident that the JSON structure will always be the same, then you can find your value like the following. (I broke it down into multiple objects and named them the same way they are named in your JSON file.)

```
    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(textData.toUtf8());
    auto rootObj = doc.object();
    auto _d = rootObj.value("_d").toArray();
    auto _t = _d[0].toObject().value("_t").toArray();
    auto _quote_min = _t[0].toObject().value("_quote_min");
    qDebug() << _quote_min;
```

Output:

```
QJsonValue(string, "2221.68")
```